# OSX Terminal hanging? - Taking a long time to do tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, installation, command

I am trying to install Ruby and do various things, i have found that terminal takes a hell of a long time to do any tasks and sometimes it doesn't complete anything, aka hangs.

```
"Mys-MacBook-Air:~ Main$ rbenv install 2.2.0
Downloading ruby-2.2.0.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7671e394abfb5d262fbcd3b27a71bf78737c7e9347fa21c39e58b0bb9c4840fc
Installing ruby-2.2.0..."
```

Then this sits for ages without showing me any feedback. It will do this with many things, including node setup and other things i have tried. Sometimes it doesn't do anything and i need to start a whole new terminal with CMD + N, Is it taking a long to download or is it installing without giving feedback? Is it normal for OSX to do this? My internet speed is 10 down so i wouldn't think it is the net.

Also, sometimes when i have finished doing something, like running a server, terminal will not go onto a new line meaning i have to reopen a new window every time, is there a way to restart the command line so i can begin typing commands again?

Comment: Did I answer your question?  If so, could you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, compiling Ruby can take a while, especially on slower machines.  On my new Macbook (maxed out), 2.1.5 took about 8 minutes to install.

To answer your question however, you can monitor that the machine is doing work using Activity Monitor (under Applications/Utilities) or use terminal tools like `top` or `htop`, the latter of which can be installed via homebrew.  You could also use `screen` or `tmux` to background the job if you don't like the idea of opening a new tab.